# Transpose transformation with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My LA textbook by Strang say there is no $2\times2$ matrix representation for linear transpose transformation on a $2\times2$ matrix. 
However, I figured out a way with matrices (not quite matrix representation though):
$$
A^\top =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am pretty sure I figured it out mostly thanks to Strang's *suggestive* problem-set. I would like to know more about this trick, would anyone be kind enough to explain to me if there is anything deeper? or where should I begin to look up?

Comment: I think you are confusing two things. A function $f$ is said to have a $m \times n$ matrix representation when $f(x)=Mx$ with $M$ a $m \times n$ matrix with respect to some basis.

Comment: @nicomezi thanks! I've just corrected my question accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question then. The formula you found is quite far from being a matrix representation (in the sense I explained in my previous comment).

Comment: @nicomezi yes, you are right. The formula is not matrix representation. I feel like sth more interesting and deep underlying it, but I am not sure what it is, and I have no clue! Therefore, my question is about what exactly is underlying this formula. (It doesn't look like mere coincidence to me.)